# Recursive Makefile to build .o files

Tags: c++, makefile

I am writing a simple kernel and all is going well so far.
I am using a Makefile to build the system through the shell.
However, I wish to move and reorganise the file structure but, my the makefile uses absolute linking.
How can I refactor this to compile all `.cpp/.c` files and `.s` files to an out folder and link them, without needing to define each folder path?

```
CC = ~/opt/cross/bin/i386-elf-g++
AS = ~/opt/cross/bin/i386-elf-as
LNFLAGS = -T linker.ld -melf_i386
CCFLAGS = -c -ffreestanding -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions
ASFLAGS = -c
CTMP = $(wildcard src/kernel/*.cpp)
ATMP = $(wildcard src/kernel/arch/i386/*.s)
CFILE = $(subst src/kernel/, ,$(CTMP))
AFILE = $(subst src/kernel/arch/i386/, ,$(ATMP))
CSRC = $(CFILE:.c=)
ASRC = $(AFILE:.s=)

OUT = $(wildcard out/*.o)

all: ccompile acompile link

ccompile:
    for file in $(CSRC) ; do \
        $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) src/kernel/$$file -o out/$$file.o ; \
    done

acompile:
    for file in $(ASRC) ; do \
        $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) src/kernel/arch/i386/$$file.s -o out/$$file.o ; \
    done

link:
    ld $(LNFLAGS) -o latest.bin $(OUT)
```

Comment: perhaps, you'd want to automate that via makefile generation, e.g. via [premake](https://premake.github.io/) or CMake. This will cost you less time and will generate correct dependencies. The direct answer to your question might be an easy extension of the makefile, but I'd consider another option

Comment: Your question is unclear. Which file paths are you trying to do without?

Comment: @Beta I am trying to compile all cpp file in all directories under the src folder.

Comment: And put all of the resultant object files in `out/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `vpath` directive to specifiy the source directories.

```
TARGETS := latest.bin

LD      := ld
LDFLAGS := -T linker.ld -melf_i386

CC      := ~/opt/cross/bin/i386-elf-g++
CCFLAGS := -c -ffreestanding -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions

AS      := ~/opt/cross/bin/i386-elf-as
ASFLAGS := -c

vpath %.cpp  src/kernel
vpath %.s    src/kernel/arch/i386

SOURCES := $(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard *.s)
OBJECTS := $(addsuffix .o, $(basename $(notdir $(SOURCES))))

all: $(TARGETS)

out/%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) -o $@ $<

out/%.o: %.s
    $(AS) $(ASFLAGS) -o $@ $<

latest.bin: $(OBJECTS)
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```